# Virtual but not multiple inheritance to call grandparent constructor

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

I'm having this kind of code:

```
class Ref {<undefined>};
Ref refObjectForA, refObjectForB;

class Base
{
  public:
    Base(const Ref & iRef) : _ref(iRef) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}

    const Ref & ref;
};

class A: public Base
{
  public:
     A() : Base(refObjectForA) {}
     virtual ~A() {}
};

class B: public A
{
  public:
    B() : Base(refObjectForB) {} // won't compile: Base is not direct base of B
    virtual ~B() {}
};
```

As the attribute is a reference, I think I can only set it in constructor, so I need to  call `Base` constructor in `B()`.
 I've found two ways: providing a "forward" constructor in `A` (but this implies adding code in all classes that *might* be inherited):

```
A(const Ref& iRef): Base(iRef)
```

or using virtual inheritance:

```
class A: public virtual Base
```

Second option allows more straightforward code in `B` implementation but I'm wondering if I'm misusing virtual inheritance in an ugly trick or if it is a valid usecase.

- Can I use virtual inheritance in this case?
- If no, for what reason?

One of the "unexpected" behaviors I've found is that it's not possible to `static_cast` a `Base` pointer to a `B` pointer because of the virtual inheritance.

Moreover I'm also wondering why it works (I mean why a `B().ref == refObjectForB`): I would think that the implicit call to default `A()` constructor in `B()` would overwrite the `ref` attribute after explicit `Base` constructor, but maybe it's not true with virtual inheritance.

Comment: Trying to "skip" a generation generally indicates a broken design. `B` shouldn't even be aware of `Base` - it should use `A`'s API only.

Comment: I don't see the point in these references, looks a bit like a type information you want to implement. You can put the "forwarding" constructor in a protected section, so it can only be used in derived classes.

Comment: Virtual bases are always constructed directly from the most derive class ctor, not from any intermediate class ctor. IOW: The call to Base::Base() in A::A() does nothing when the object being constructed is a B.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree with your comment, but in my case I have code generically dealing with `Base` objects and its `ref` attribute, and `A` and `B` classes are "client" classes. My aim is to not prevent several inheritance levels below `Base` but providing a way to have specific `ref` values for each child classes.

Comment: leemes: Yes it was my design choice.
n.m.: it at least explains why it "works", thanks!

Comment: @FredericS: Then perhaps `B` should derive that functionality from a _direct_ base.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that's why I'm suggesting in answer's comments to explicitly virtually inherits from `Base` in `B`, but that might not be a clean solution either... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option I can see if you want to stick to your inheritance hierarchy is to implement protected constructors taking a reference which they'll forward to the `Base` class. Making a constructor protected makes sure that a (final) instance can't be constructed using this constructor, so it will only be used in subclasses to initialize the super classes.

With some more or less ugly and dangerous macro, this becomes easy to be written:

```
#define REF_FORWARD_CTOR(ClassName, DirectSuperClassName) \
    protected: ClassName(class Ref &r) : DirectSuperClassName(r) {} \
    public:

class A : public Base
{
    REF_FORWARD_CTOR(A, Base)
public:
    A() : Base(refObjectForA) {} // normal ctor
};

class B : public A
{
    REF_FORWARD_CTOR(B, A)
public:
    B() : A(refObjectForB) {} // normal ctor
};
```

An alternative design would be to let `A` and `B` both derive (directly) from `Base`. Then, add functionalities by using multiple inheritance and "common classes", maybe private, depending on what they are for:

```
class Base {
};

class Common {
    // common stuff used by both A and B
};

class A : public Base, public Common {
    // no further stuff here
};

class B : public Base, public Common {
    // add more stuff, or put it in a common super-class again,
    // if some classes want to inherit from B again
};
```

The problem with this design is that functionality in `Common` can't access the stuff in `A` and `B`. To solve this, do one of the following:

- If only static stuff is required: Use [CRTP](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern) to specify `A` / `B` in a concrete `Common` type: `Common<A>` can then use `A::...`, but doesn't have anything to do with a concrete instance of `A`
- If an instance is required: provide a pointer / reference in the constructor of `Common` (slight overhead)
- Putting the first two solutions together: Use CRTP, implement wrapper functions in `A` and `B` which call functions in `Common<A>` and `Common<B>` providing `this` (which is a `A*` or `B*` via an extra parameter.
- Same as above, but the class `Common` can also be non-templated (no CRTP) if you overload / template these functions on this pointer argument ("CRTP on functions", if you want to call it like that). [Code speaks louder than words.](http://ideone.com/wFDygc) (Example code is without your references and focuses on the "common class".)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! What is your opinion about expliciting virtual inheritance of `Base` in `B`, with `class B: public A, public virtual Base`?

Comment: Edit: I'm not sure with this: The problem with that is that when initializing `A` in the ctor of `B` an instance of `Base` already has been initialized. The same instance of `Base` is then reused for the virtual inheritance of `Base` in `B`. So you can't put the `refObjectForB` in the `Base` in this case!

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can technically use virtual inheritance to achieve the goal of providing the reference in the most derived class.

And yes, that's a design smell.

Your classes should not need to be aware of anything but their immediate bases (virtual inheritance is the exception to the rule, when it's needed for other reasons).

Comment: But isn't then the problem that when initializing `A` in the ctor of `B` already sets the `refObjectForA`, and then the virtual inheritance "reuses" this instance of `Base`? Or is it / can it be the other way around, depending on the order of super constructor calls in the ctor of `B`?

Comment: @leemes I'm adding logs in my real case example and the construction order is `Base, A, B`. But I think the `Base` constructor is called in `B` first and thus the `Base` constructor in `A()` is not called (only one `Base` log) as the `Base` part is already constructed (see n.m. comment in question). But this confirms it's a design smell :D

Comment: there is exactly one constructor call on each sub-object. with virtual inheritance the virtual base is initialized by the most derived class, initializations higher up in the hierarchy are ignored. this means it's technically ok, as i wrote, but still a design smell

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to the proposed classes hierarchy, in order to solve the problem it is enough to use the "using-declaration" to bring the Base's constructor to the protected part of the class A, i.e.:

```
class A: public Base
{
  public:
     A() : Base(refObjectForA) {}
     virtual ~A() {}
  protected:
    using Base::Base;
};
```